# php use variable name when call static property

Tags: php, oop

I have a problem when call static property:

`const LOW = 'somethg';`

When I try like that it's ok:
    `$arrv = FuzzyClass::$terms[$pk][FuzzyQuery::LOW];`

But I need to use variable name and it doesn't work:

```
$pv = 'LOW';
$arrv = FuzzyClass::$terms[$pk][FuzzyQuery::$pv];
```

Comment: Try `FuzzyClass::$terms[$pk][FuzzyQuery::{$pv}];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arrv = FuzzyClass::$terms[$pk][constant(FuzzyQuery::$pv)];
```

`FuzzyQuery::$pv` is just a string containing `LOW`, thus calling that way returns `low` as string. Use constant identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstant.php):

```
class FuzzyQuery {
    const LOW = 'somethg';
}

class FuzzyClass {
    public static $terms = ['index' => ['somethg' => 'Hello']];
}

$pk = 'index';
$pv = 'LOW';

$reflection = new ReflectionClass('FuzzyQuery');
$arrv = FuzzyClass::$terms[$pk][$reflection->getConstant($pv)];

echo $arrv . PHP_EOL; // Hello
```